# Show flash message after user open specific page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need create flash notification after user open specific page.

For example: we have page "A" in website menu. User click to link and open page "A". And after page "A" loading - showing

`flash[:note] = page_a.note_message`

And every time when user open page "A" - again showing this notification

Comment: ok, so what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, adding values to the flash will make them available to the next request, but if you need to access those values in the same request you can use `flash.now` in the controller.
You can read more about it in the [Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#flash-now)